# python asyncio socket low speed on every first connection

Tags: python, performance, sockets, python-asyncio

I have async web server of python that uses asyncio python module.

The first part of code to start server is:

```
def handleData(reader, writer): 
    time_list=[]
    total_start=time.time()

    print(reader._transport._extra['peername'][0]+':'+str(reader._transport._extra['peername'][1]))
    message=''
    clientip=''
    data=bytearray()    
    start=time.time()
    data=yield from reader.read(1024)
    time2=time.time()-start        
    time_list.append(['Time2',str(time2)])              
    message=data.decode(encoding='utf-8')    
    if message=='':
        return


    if '\r\n\r\n' not in message:
        while '\r\n\r\n' not in message:
            data=yield from reader.read(1024)
            message+=data.decode(encoding='utf-8')

    retval=header(message)    


def main():               
    loop = get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(ServerClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 80)
    srv = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

after searching and putting time calculation in different areas of my code, I've found that the first line of getting
socket data from client, is lowest and most time consuming part ( data=yield from reader.read(1024) )
the line before (time2=time.time()-start) line.

what's the problem? I can't understand why its so low and
eveytime gets 3-4 seconds, but other parts just 100 ms.

Comment: still nobody wants to answer? Is this maybe asyncio library documentation is poor?

Comment: hello, please answer :((((((((

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I don't understand. will you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `read` [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L627) you'll see this part:

```
if not self._buffer and not self._eof:
    yield from self._wait_for_data('read')

# This will work right even if buffer is less than n bytes
data = bytes(self._buffer[:n])
del self._buffer[:n]
```

`read` may actually do some job only after first call to fill `_buffer` with data and on further calls just return pieces of it. It can explain why first `read` call is more consuming then others.

I don't know if 100 ms is normal situation for awaiting `_wait_for_data`, it depends on how implemented [protocol](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L252) that `feed_data` your reader and how transport calls protocol's `data_received`.

Afaiu, you use your own protocol/transport, so it's impossible to say if you do things right there, but here few advices for you:

1. Enable [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode-of-asyncio) with `loop.set_debug(True)` to see if
   asyncio has something to tell you.
2. Try to use [debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0) to see what happens on that first `read` call.